# If $A$ is a real matrix, $A^2=A$, $x^TA^TAx\leq x^Tx$. Show $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ real matrix, $A^2=A$, $x^TA^TAx\leq x^Tx$, $\forall\ x\in \Bbb R^n$. Show $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

From $A^2=A$, we know there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal, with entries $0$ or $1$. Then what next?

Comment: I'm not sure yet if this helps, but the inequality can be interpreted as $||Ax|| \leq ||x||$, where $||x||$ means the Euclidean norm of $x$.

Comment: @user49640 Yes, Then what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will prove that $A$ is an orthogonal projection.

Because $A^2 = A$, we know that $A$ is the projection parallel to its kernel $N$ onto its range $I$, and $N \oplus I = R^n$. We need to prove that $N$ and $I$ are orthogonal.

Let $x \in N$ and $y \in I$. Let $u_a = y + ax$ for $a \in R$. By the given inequality, we have $||Au_a||^2 \leq ||u_a||^2$, or $||y||^2 \leq ||y + ax||^2$. Thus, for all $a \in R$, we have
$$2a\langle x, y\rangle + a^2||x||^2 \geq 0.$$

Considering the left-hand side as a quadratic function of $a$, we see that this is possible only if $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$. Therefore $N$ and $I$ are orthogonal, as desired.